# how to do a spearman correlation matrix for each of my independent variables?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I am asking for help to make a spearman correlation matrix where I can visualize how in each **conditions** if there are correlations between **TAC** (dependent variable) and **concentration**? If possible with `p.adjust` included.

The type of matrix I'm looking for is one that is easy to read, with Spearman's p and p-value included. My thanks to anyone who can help me or point me in the right direction.

here is my data frame:

```
> str(table5)
'data.frame':   280 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ treatment    : chr  "control" "control" "control" "control" ...
 $ concentration: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ day          : chr  "day 00" "day 00" "day 00" "day 00" ...
 $ TAC          : num  0.0135 0.0162 0.0146 0.0153 0.0128 ...
 $ conditions   : Factor w/ 15 levels "controlday 00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
> dput(table5)
structure(list(treatment = c("control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn"), concentration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), day = c("day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28"), 
    TAC = c(0.0134723395589115, 0.0161888871061509, 0.0146337654145718, 
    0.0153067871292595, 0.012800314735395, 0.0160841665978896, 
    0.0140621616691814, 0.0135425580967982, 0.0132198270328205, 
    0.0138496077219653, 0.0135775493518084, 0.0126333962864469, 
    0.0164821881641534, 0.0132516331108305, 0.0157791571175251, 
    0.0129960024291699, 0.0146323678504021, 0.0134451215151322, 
    0.0143262838325461, 0.0153573779185249, 0.0139773746147923, 
    0.0159350865128266, 0.0156720782857077, 0.0155096081292032, 
    0.013476349735956, 0.0140104181996115, 0.0129878390010014, 
    0.0147239859165112, 0.015160930718777, 0.0148955399340424, 
    0.013274378116328, 0.0153663044374496, 0.0145472559523844, 
    0.0132898660703847, 0.0139871399975842, 0.0124985111701027, 
    0.0149240276338179, 0.0129573902698069, 0.0147729343794709, 
    0.0128674264777598, 0.0147815872982594, 0.0139767796824041, 
    0.0144185398405766, 0.0155799146991459, 0.0135417909851351, 
    0.015988596586438, 0.0139603963976125, 0.0126397298299191, 
    0.013297964384596, 0.012347536157165, 0.0152573470818857, 
    0.0136566619097667, 0.0125192707022401, 0.0141156296691061, 
    0.0139603724286662, 0.0141388938152221, 0.0127749097766803, 
    0.0142082519110294, 0.0149398326676766, 0.0143207529313558, 
    0.0144381103787128, 0.0149147414885484, 0.0139224295866318, 
    0.0161358891403436, 0.0151690152511571, 0.0120945286936824, 
    0.0153132383654698, 0.0131770823852777, 0.0136750345235747, 
    0.0129352436377984, 0.0162120454010317, 0.0155409171425954, 
    0.0135940425474181, 0.0142951343511937, 0.0143779323175896, 
    0.0136891451722703, 0.0140286347004686, 0.0122667606250391, 
    0.0152446224172418, 0.013442306549535, 0.0129068996979612, 
    0.0147404146947943, 0.013688825582269, 0.0130193063055386, 
    0.01285971255513, 0.0151660181611206, 0.0138280467330508, 
    0.0135147736966651, 0.0158580706409006, 0.0149366602534351, 
    0.0106554950909403, 0.0179654260106192, 0.0120425346368713, 
    0.0145387164119486, 0.0139546280207597, 0.0121871897075845, 
    0.0150418870034593, 0.0148117380734173, 0.0139690179111281, 
    0.0170751257982307, 0.0129661477952429, 0.0144612227917873, 
    0.0146065893466387, 0.0126241343210384, 0.0170751257982307, 
    0.0130964557093226, 0.0134570968344701, 0.0165480203562944, 
    0.0151921149184481, 0.0130666062376204, 0.012722050697886, 
    0.0155582048904096, 0.0125288074742436, 0.016985639190516, 
    0.0176528351294189, 0.0138432089287227, 0.013890319218671, 
    0.017035215335001, 0.0168839977227436, 0.0133203267470888, 
    0.013892777179513, 0.0155216139064973, 0.0130076218759369, 
    0.013903958340264, 0.0135000204009635, 0.0148519977852621, 
    0.0153029154169557, 0.0141832966293512, 0.0176005510379328, 
    0.0180687740940438, 0.0177789446952697, 0.0182099087520794, 
    0.0184723827329167, 0.022483746075728, 0.0196648164641345, 
    0.0170131886149416, 0.0215058343136062, 0.0211259597744559, 
    0.0196373761289472, 0.0206737739206, 0.020532594441278, 0.0193494766153245, 
    0.0211617300063814, 0.0213333413267872, 0.0202163436360403, 
    0.0236752367085596, 0.0231873026647459, 0.0228522660496144, 
    0.0238366734630018, 0.0264524093818515, 0.0268093919646026, 
    0.0252668406573153, 0.0258403852690662, 0.0223986018317785, 
    0.0272147558779617, 0.0225116847733454, 0.0247724813762193, 
    0.022691182948792, 0.0235805783268122, 0.0270689051186104, 
    0.0126334908832258, 0.0164665820507107, 0.0129386884401034, 
    0.0119158011756844, 0.0130928729787235, 0.0149940706645974, 
    0.0129535502638655, 0.0162831996423606, 0.0176755444192191, 
    0.0161755659998132, 0.0174173101524856, 0.0155714069341957, 
    0.01433383826834, 0.0143819293817603, 0.0185494616259894, 
    0.0140319779691521, 0.0144114680062016, 0.0174497227904159, 
    0.0180907703704672, 0.0157478259355293, 0.0158958906812569, 
    0.0147163839619763, 0.0146701443994308, 0.0180369287296324, 
    0.0149336258279806, 0.0186097801562105, 0.0137231521985133, 
    0.0153650910635747, 0.0138998273293687, 0.0155199902217533, 
    0.0163903022171882, 0.015754928008943, 0.0171808546793322, 
    0.0154244829039175, 0.0134954450270778, 0.0147187179502944, 
    0.0160939056001929, 0.0145497150558122, 0.0154571534643691, 
    0.015511148172344, 0.0132885919777709, 0.0138910418368534, 
    0.0152496449072613, 0.0132820365830201, 0.013480084079182, 
    0.016683045565325, 0.0176337406920335, 0.0151657804062655, 
    0.0125455114843902, 0.0118102856445592, 0.0116410665300014, 
    0.0146556231989517, 0.014464999427952, 0.0121229802720933, 
    0.0146834533301593, 0.0121645122630423, 0.0136816673389857, 
    0.0135984961089614, 0.0164906141382343, 0.0149265724276527, 
    0.0163311308492402, 0.017967595623527, 0.0143263172313383, 
    0.0145117513172078, 0.0149694356038913, 0.0136478358101476, 
    0.0148523043836901, 0.0140267859486034, 0.0136857372651645, 
    0.0161384954212, 0.0171836598216303, 0.0165288287203719, 
    0.0163703032374203, 0.0149628937118673, 0.0167639896711626, 
    0.0144140290861155, 0.0164700832677882, 0.017097353142466, 
    0.0177233791174971, 0.016410406871025, 0.0145656397252108, 
    0.0127795571441824, 0.0139787766512734, 0.0145603577832239, 
    0.0130325210010334, 0.0157142193796273, 0.0165295708322065, 
    0.0154878492755022, 0.0176888974165639, 0.0186435561581489, 
    0.0177330425080685, 0.0182856446463086, 0.0219973970170363, 
    0.0217533371623466, 0.0176290655250839, 0.0202192044566584, 
    0.01917805317661, 0.0186277616395779, 0.0170154664932417, 
    0.0195884686724334, 0.0201420675026667, 0.0183148068985733, 
    0.020836323932372, 0.0207067552945439, 0.018534989031893, 
    0.019680916901509, 0.0219673944081694, 0.0236890701508884, 
    0.0235543150426157, 0.0234233849979097, 0.0210565415662947, 
    0.0232511101944444, 0.0227186732866978, 0.0225332903957415, 
    0.0234773944195847, 0.0229988542468931, 0.022618525386521, 
    0.0197686090869307, 0.0186686467858637, 0.0189525178016395
    ), conditions = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), levels = c("controlday 00", 
    "controlday 07", "controlday 14", "controlday 21", "controlday 28", 
    "nZnday 00", "nZnday 07", "nZnday 14", "nZnday 21", "nZnday 28", 
    "Znday 00", "Znday 07", "Znday 14", "Znday 21", "Znday 28"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-280L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `split` the data frame by `conditions`, use `lapply` to get the `cor.test` from each sub-data frame and create a one-row data frame of group/correlation/pvalue from each, which you then `rbind` into a single data frame.

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(table5, table5$conditions), function(d) { 
  x <- cor.test(d$concentration, d$TAC, method = 'spearman')
  data.frame(group = d$conditions[1], cor = x$estimate, 
             p = scales::pvalue(x$p.value, add_p = TRUE))
})) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)
#>            group         cor       p
#> 1  controlday 00          NA    <NA>
#> 2  controlday 07          NA    <NA>
#> 3  controlday 14          NA    <NA>
#> 4  controlday 21          NA    <NA>
#> 5  controlday 28          NA    <NA>
#> 6      nZnday 00 -0.05160468 p=0.811
#> 7      nZnday 07  0.70034929 p<0.001
#> 8      nZnday 14  0.71509349 p<0.001
#> 9      nZnday 21  0.73720978 p<0.001
#> 10     nZnday 28  0.78144237 p<0.001
#> 11      Znday 00  0.23590713 p=0.267
#> 12      Znday 07  0.46444216 p=0.022
#> 13      Znday 14  0.56765153 p=0.004
#> 14      Znday 21  0.65611670 p<0.001
#> 15      Znday 28  0.81830286 p<0.001
```

The first four groups all have NA values, because the value of `concentration` is 0 for the entire group and the standard deviation is therefore 0.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` - assuming the OP meant for `cor.test` as the P value are being asked.  Grouped by 'treatment', 'day' conditions', apply the `cor.test` on the TAC, concentration, convert the `list` output to a tibble with `broom::tidy` and `unnest` the `tibble` column

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
table5 %>%
   reframe(cor = broom::tidy(cor.test(TAC, concentration,
    method = "spearman")), .by = c("treatment", "day", "conditions")) %>% 
   unnest(where(is_tibble))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 8
   treatment day    conditions    estimate statistic     p.value method                          alternative
   <chr>     <chr>  <fct>            <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                           <chr>      
 1 control   day 00 controlday 00  NA            NA  NA          Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 2 control   day 07 controlday 07  NA            NA  NA          Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 3 control   day 14 controlday 14  NA            NA  NA          Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 4 control   day 21 controlday 21  NA            NA  NA          Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 5 control   day 28 controlday 28  NA            NA  NA          Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 6 nZn       day 00 nZnday 00      -0.0516     2419.  0.811      Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 7 nZn       day 07 nZnday 07       0.700       689.  0.000139   Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 8 nZn       day 14 nZnday 14       0.715       655.  0.0000860  Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
 9 nZn       day 21 nZnday 21       0.737       604.  0.0000396  Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
10 nZn       day 28 nZnday 28       0.781       503.  0.00000654 Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
11 Zn        day 00 Znday 00        0.236      1757.  0.267      Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
12 Zn        day 07 Znday 07        0.464      1232.  0.0222     Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
13 Zn        day 14 Znday 14        0.568       994.  0.00381    Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
14 Zn        day 21 Znday 21        0.656       791.  0.000499   Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided  
15 Zn        day 28 Znday 28        0.818       418.  0.00000103 Spearman's rank correlation rho two.sided
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this base R solution:

```
ll <- split(df, df$condition)
sprtest <- lapply(ll, function(x) cor.test(x$TAC, x$concentration, method = "spearman")[c("estimate", "p.value")])
do.call(rbind, lapply(sprtest, unlist))
```

Alternatively, in base R you could use `by` to avoid `split`ting:

```
by(df, df$condition, FUN = function(x) 
  unlist(cor.test(x$TAC, x$concentration, method = "spearman")[c("estimate", "p.value")]))
do.call(rbind, xx)
```

Either way, the output is:

```
#               estimate.rho      p.value
# controlday 00           NA           NA
# controlday 07           NA           NA
# controlday 14           NA           NA
# controlday 21           NA           NA
# controlday 28           NA           NA
# nZnday 00      -0.05160468 8.107384e-01
# nZnday 07       0.70034929 1.386591e-04
# nZnday 14       0.71509349 8.597702e-05
# nZnday 21       0.73720978 3.964055e-05
# nZnday 28       0.78144237 6.541909e-06
# Znday 00        0.23590713 2.671011e-01
# Znday 07        0.46444216 2.222910e-02
# Znday 14        0.56765153 3.812867e-03
# Znday 21        0.65611670 4.987260e-04
# Znday 28        0.81830286 1.031562e-06
```